# Converting Excel function to TypeScript function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to convert the following Excel's function (factor =1/(1+disc_rate)^(A2-base_yr) to TypeScript function. TypeScript is new to me, can look at this code and let me know what I'm doing wrong? I'm getting 0 value when running the code using the TypeScript Playground environment. Also, not sure if the `Math.pow` statement is correct. I'm basically trying to replicate the Excel's factor formula in TypeScript. Thanks

```
var base = 10
var rate = 7
var risk = 0.5
function npv(base: number, rate: number, risk: number){
    var factor = Math.pow((1/(1+rate)), base)
    return factor * risk
}
console.log(npv(base, rate, risk))
```

Comment: what error or unexpected result are you getting? Can you provide some additional details to the question?

Comment: I'm getting 0 value when running the code

Comment: I'm using TypeScript Playground to test the code

Comment: You are effectively doing 0.125^2021. What are you expecting the power to be?  (I'm guessing not 2021)

Comment: Note that your 3 variable declarations of 10, 7, and .5 at the top of the function arent used.  You are logging the method being performed with 2021, 7, and .5

Comment: is the formula you're trying to replicate the discount factor formula?

Comment: Should it  be `1 / Math.pow(((1+rate)), base)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you're not sure if the `Math.pow` statement is correct.

For your specific use case it should be:

```
var factor = 1 / Math.pow(((1+rate)), base)
```